# ffmpeg keeping full title when encoding

Tags: powershell, encoding, ffmpeg

I am trying to name the audio and sub files in the batch encode using  the title tag in the meta data.   the issue im running into is if the title says English Commentary  it will only grab  English  or Jap uncut it will only grab Jap.

```
$audioTracks = ffprobe $f.FullName -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=title -select_streams a -of compact=p=0:nk=1 
$audioTracks = $audioTracks.split("")
foreach($audio in $audioTracks) {
    $ID = $audio.split("|")[0];
    $audioName = $audio.split("|")[1];
    ffmpeg -i $f.FullName -threads 0 -muxdelay 0 -y -map 0:$ID -codec aac -f segment -segment_time 10 -segment_list_size 0 -segment_list out/$f/audio/audio_"$audioName.m3u8" -segment_format mpegts out/$f/audio/"audio_$audioName%d.ts"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $sw = [Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()
 $files = Get-ChildItem ${Get-Location}
 $loco = Get-Location
 $p1 = Join-Path -Path $loco -ChildPath "/out"
 New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $p1



 function lnCodeTransform {
param( $String )
echo $String
switch ($String)
{
    "jpn" {"jp"}
    "eng" {"en"}
    "esp" {"es"}
    "fra" {"fr"}
    "deu" {"de"}
    default {$String}
    }
  }


function lnNameTransform {
param( $String )
switch ($String)
{
    "jpn" {"Japanese"}
    "eng" {"English"}
    "esp" {"Spanish"}
    "fra" {"French"}
    "deu" {"German"}
    default {$String}
   }
  }


foreach ($f in $files){ 
if ($f.Name -eq "out"){
    continue;
}
$p2 = Join-Path -Path $loco -ChildPath "/out/" | Join-Path -ChildPath $f
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $p2/audio
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $p2/video
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $p2/subtitle
$sb = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new();
[void]$sb.AppendLine( '#EXTM3U' )
[void]$sb.AppendLine( '#EXT-X-VERSION:3' )
#[void]$sb.AppendLine( '#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=800000,RESOLUTION=640x360' )
#[void]$sb.AppendLine( '360p.m3u8' )


New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $p2
$resStr = ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=height -of csv=s=x:p=0 $f.FullName;
$res = [convert]::ToInt32($resStr)
$audioTracks = ffprobe $f.FullName -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -select_streams a -of compact=p=0:nk=1 
$audioTracks = $audioTracks.split("\n")
foreach($audio in $audioTracks) {
    $ID = $audio.split("|")[0];
    $audioName = $audio.split("|")[1];
    ffmpeg -i $f.FullName -threads 0 -muxdelay 0 -y -map 0:$ID -codec aac -f segment -segment_time 10 -segment_list_size 0 -segment_list out/$f/audio/audio_"$ID.m3u8" -segment_format mpegts out/$f/audio/"audio_$ID""_%d.ts"
    $name = lnNameTransform($audioName)
    $code = lnCodeTransform($audioName)
    [void]$sb.AppendLine( "#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=AUDIO,GROUP-ID=`"aac`",LANGUAGE=`"$code`",NAME=`"$name`",DEFAULT=NO,AUTOSELECT=NO,URI=`"audio/audio_$ID.m3u8`"" )
}
$subTracks = ffprobe $f.FullName -show_entries stream=index:stream_tags=language -select_streams s -of compact=p=0:nk=1 
$subTracks = $subTracks.split("")
foreach($subtitle in $subTracks) {
    $ID = $subtitle.split("|")[0];
    $subName = $subtitle.split("|")[1];
    ffmpeg -i $f.FullName -map 0:$ID -f segment -segment_time 10 -segment_list_size 0 -segment_list out/$f/subtitle/sub_"$subName.m3u8" -segment_format webvtt -scodec webvtt out/$f/subtitle/"sub_$subName%d.vtt"
    $name = lnNameTransform($subName)
    $code = lnCodeTransform($subName)
    [void]$sb.AppendLine( "#EXT-X-MEDIA:TYPE=SUBTITLES,GROUP-ID=`"subs`",LANGUAGE=`"$code`",NAME=`"$name`",FORCED=NO,AUTOSELECT=NO,URI=`"subtitle/sub_$subName.m3u8`"" )
}

[void]$sb.AppendLine( '#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=1400000,CODECS="avc1.4d4015,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=842x480,AUDIO="aac",SUBTITLES="subs"' )
[void]$sb.AppendLine( 'video/480p.m3u8' )
#ffmpeg -i $f.FullName -c:a copy -vf scale=w=640:h=360:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -c:a aac -ar 48000  -rc cqp -qp_p 0 -qp_i 1 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod  -b:v 800k -maxrate 856k -bufsize 1200k -b:a 96k -hls_segment_filename out/$f/360p_%03d.ts out/$f/360p.m3u8 -vf scale=w=842:h=480:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -c:a aac -ar 48000 -gpu 1 -c:v h264_amf -rc cqp -qp_p 0 -qp_i 1 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod -b:v 1400k -maxrate 1498k -bufsize 2100k -b:a 128k -hls_segment_filename out/$f/480p_%03d.ts out/$f/480p.m3u8 -vf  scale=w=1280:h=720:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -c:a aac -ar 48000 -gpu 1 -c:v h264_amf -rc cqp -qp_p 0 -qp_i 1 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod -b:v 2800k -maxrate 2996k -bufsize 4200k -b:a 128k -hls_segment_filename out/$f/720p_%03d.ts out/$f/720p.m3u8 -vf  scale=w=1920:h=1080:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease -c:a aac -ar 48000 -gpu 1 -c:v h264_amf -rc cqp -qp_p 0 -qp_i 1 -profile:v main -crf 20 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -keyint_min 48 -hls_time 4 -hls_playlist_type vod -b:v 5000k -maxrate 5350k -bufsize 7500k -b:a 192k -hls_segment_filename out/$f/1080p_%03d.ts out/$f/1080p.m3u8
#ffmpeg -hwaccel auto -hwaccel_device 0 -i $f.FullName -c:v h264_nvenc -preset slow -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -filter:v scale=360:640 -ar 48000  -rc cqp -qp_p 0 -qp_i 1 -profile:v main -crf 23 -sc_threshold 0 -g 48 -b:v 800k -maxrate 856k -bufsize 1200k -b:a 96k  -keyint_min 4 -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_playlist_type vod  -hls_list_size 0 -f hls -hls_segment_filename out/$f/360p_%03d.ts out/$f/360p.m3u8 
#ffmpeg -hwaccel auto -hwaccel_device 0 -i $f.FullName -c:v h264 -profile:v main -c:a aac -filter:v scale=360:640 -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls -hls_segment_filename out/$f/360p_%03d.ts out/$f/360p.m3u8 
ffmpeg -i $f.FullName -c:v h264_nvenc -crf 22 -preset slow -pix_fmt yuv420p -filter:v scale="trunc(oh*a/2)*2:480" -map 0:v -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls -hls_segment_filename out/$f/video/480p_%03d.ts out/$f/video/480p.m3u8
If($res -ge 720) {
    ffmpeg -i $f.FullName -c:v h264_nvenc -crf 20 -preset slow -pix_fmt yuv420p -filter:v scale="trunc(oh*a/2)*2:720" -map 0:v -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls -hls_segment_filename out/$f/video/720p_%03d.ts out/$f/video/720p.m3u8
    [void]$sb.AppendLine( '#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=2800000,CODECS="avc1.4d4015,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1280x720,AUDIO="aac",SUBTITLES="subs"' )
    [void]$sb.AppendLine( 'video/720p.m3u8' )
}   
If($res -ge 1080) {
    ffmpeg -i $f.FullName -c:v h264_nvenc -crf 18 -preset slow -pix_fmt yuv420p -filter:v scale="trunc(oh*a/2)*2:1080" -map 0:v -start_number 0 -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 0 -f hls -hls_segment_filename out/$f/video/1080p_%03d.ts out/$f/video/1080p.m3u8
    [void]$sb.AppendLine( '#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=5000000,CODECS="avc1.4d4015,mp4a.40.2",RESOLUTION=1920x1080,AUDIO="aac",SUBTITLES="subs"' )
    [void]$sb.AppendLine( 'video/1080p.m3u8' )
}

$p3 = Join-Path -Path $p2 -ChildPath "/index.m3u8"
#echo $index | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 -LiteralPath $p3
echo $sb.ToString()
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($p3, $sb.ToString().Trim().replace("`r`n", "`n"))
 }
 sw.Stop()
  echo $sw.Elapsed
```